# Which knots' stick numbers are twice their crossing numbers?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, knot-theory, stick-knots

Looking at a table of minimum [stick numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick_number) for knots ([table here](http://www.colab.sfu.ca/KnotPlot/sticknumbers/)), 
it seems the known upper bound of $2 c(K)$ in terms of the knot [crossing number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(knot_theory)) $c(K)$
is realized by the trefoil $3_1$—it requires 6 sticks (see image below) and its crossing number is 3—but not by any other small knot, at least through cursory inspection.
Whence the question in the title: Are there other knots whose minimal stick number reaches the upper
bound of twice its crossing number? This is probably well-known (perhaps well-known to be unknown),
in which case a reference would suffice.  Thanks!

[image]

**Addendum**.
I found a 12-year old answer to my question
in a paper by 
Eric Furstenberg, Jie Lie, and Jodi Schneider [FLS]:

> "Thus far, the trefoil is the only knot to realize Negami’s 
>   upper bound of $2c[K]$ on the 
>   stick number. 
>   Do other such knots exist, and if so, what are their similarities to the 
>   trefoil?"

If anyone knows of more recent information, I would appreciate
hearing of it.  Thanks!

[FLS]
"Stick Knots."
Eric Furstenberg, Jie Lie, and Jodi Schneider.
*Chaos, Solitons & Fractals*, Vol. 9, No. 4-5, pp. 561-568, 1998.
[Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TJ4-3TB061X-5&_user=825413&_coverDate=05%252F31%252F1998&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1473672271&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000044660&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=825413&md5=5c6b10f15ee4d1b3999db2703e43bc51&searchtype=a)

Comment: http://newweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/KnotPlot/msgetknot?knot=0.1 made me spit out my coffee.

Comment: Ha!!! But why were you looking at $0_1$ in the first place? :-)

Comment: I had no idea what you were talking about, but I was curious, so I started at the top.

Comment: Related 2014 reference: "[Equilateral stick number of knots](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7383)."

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/S0960-0779(97)00093-3](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0960-0779(97)00093-3) ([Zbl 0933.57003](https://zbmath.org/0933.57003)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just read the following paper, where an answer can be found:

Youngsik Huh, Seungsang Oh, *An upper bound on stick number of knots*, J. Knot Theory Ram. **20** (2011), no. 5, 741–747, [doi: 10.1142/S0218216511008966](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218216511008966), [arXiv: 1512.03592](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03592).

There it is shown that the trefoil is the only knot whose stick number equals twice its crossing number. 
This is a consequence of the authors' main result (Thm. 1.1), which states that any nontrivial knot $K$ satisfies $s(K)\leq \frac{3}{2}(c(K)+1)$ (thus improving Negami's upper bound).

Comment: That $\frac{3}{2}$ bound is nice!  Thanks for posting this update.

Comment: Huh & Oh have posted their paper to the arXiv: [arXiv:1512.03592](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03592).