# Is the unit-stick number of a knot equal to its stick number?

Tags: discrete-geometry, open-problems, stick-knots

Define the *unit-stick number* $\sigma_1(K)$ of a knot $K$ to be the fewest unit-length
sticks that can realize $K$.
Clearly $\sigma_1(K)$ is at least the stick number $\sigma(K)$.
It is known that the trefoil knot $K_{3_1}$ has stick number $6$;
see the image below.
I believe, although I don't have a formal proof, that $\sigma_1(K_{3_1})=6$:
the trefoil also has unit-stick number $6$.

[image]

<sup>([Wikipedia image by Wiebew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick_number). The sticks are not all the same length.)</sup>

> ***Q***. Is $\sigma_1(K) = \sigma(K)$ for every knot $K$?
> If not, what is a knot for which it can be proved that
> the unit-stick number is strictly greater than the stick number,
> $\sigma_1(K) > \sigma(K)$?

---

Related: [Which knots' stick numbers are twice their crossing numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/39870/6094).

---

*Update.* User @aorq's comment shows that my "unit-stick number" has been studied under the name "equilateral stick number":

> Rawdon, Eric J., and Robert G. Scharein. "Upper bounds for equilateral stick numbers." *Contemporary Mathematics* 304 (2002): 55-76.

These authors proved that indeed the trefoil has equilateral stick
number $6$. They identify the $8_{19}$ knot as possibly one
whose equilateral stick number is greater than its stick number.
So, about $20$ years ago, it appears that the question I posed was an open problem.

[image: TrefoilEqStick]

Comment: http://www.colab.sfu.ca/KnotPlot/eqsticks.pdf

Comment: Apparently "Kenneth C Millett. Physical knot theory: An introduction to the study of the influence of knotting on
the spatial characteristics of polymers. In Louis H Kauffman, Sofia Lambropoulou, Slavik Jablan, and
Jozef H Przytycki, editors, ´ Introductory Lectures on Knot Theory, volume 46 of Series on Knots and
Everything, pages 346–378. World Scientific Publishing, Singapore, 2012" finds that $8_{19}$ specifically is not a counterexample. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00917